# how to load a script with a document.write with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, appendchild, document.write

I want to display an advertisement in my page loaded with AJAX/jQuery-JSON.

- The script:
- The file xxxxx.js contains a  document.write ();

How to integrate this script and make the document.write be interpreted.
and why it does not work?

here is my test revealed that the script is executed because the alert ('hello 1') is displayed but not document.write that contains the alert ('hello 2');

Call the file directly into the DOM execute well "hello 1" and "hello 2"

**test.js**

```
alert("hello 1");
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">alert("hello 2");</scr'+'ipt>');
```

**index :**

```
<body>
<script>
function loadScriptJs() {
var s = document.createElement('script'); 
s.src = 'test.js';  
s.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementById("pub").appendChild(s);
}
</script>
<div id="pub">
    PUB A AJOUTER CI DESSOUS EN JAVASCRIPT  :
    <!--  appel direct de la pub 
    <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
</div>
<script> loadScriptJs(); </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add a script with `appendChild`, it's loaded asynchronously. So when your code in test.js runs, chances are the DOM is already constructed, and `document.write` will overwrite all page contents.

It looks like the most simple solution is to replace this:

```
<script> loadScriptJs(); </script>
```

with:

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

The other option is to not use `document.write` at all inside test.js. From `loadScriptJs`, set a callback for script load (`s.onload = function() { /* loaded */ })`), then inject the ad into the DOM from that callback.

Comment: sorry for my english :) 
thank you bfavaretto  but I can not use the simple solution

in order to make a hit for each load : I have to load the script each loading content, the function will be executed after loading my content

Comment: Okay, but then you can't use document.write in `test.js`. See my update.